# why <h1> tag is not display using backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I am trying to load one html file using backbone js and require js file .I am able to call initialise function   of view but not able to load that html file  here is my code

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'text!templates/stats.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, statsTemplate) {
    'use strict';
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
        // the App already present in the HTML.
        el: '#todoapp',

        // Compile our stats template
        template: _.template(statsTemplate),

        // Delegated events for creating new items, and clearing completed ones.
        events: {

        },

        // At initialization we bind to the relevant events on the `Todos`
        // collection, when items are added or changed. Kick things off by
        // loading any preexisting todos that might be saved in *localStorage*.
        initialize: function () {


   alert('-in--')
        },

        // Re-rendering the App just means refreshing the statistics -- the rest
        // of the app doesn't change.
        render: function () {

        }
        // Add a single todo item to the list by creating a view for it, and
        // appending its element to the `<ul>`.



    });

    return AppView;

})
```

I am getting the alert in **initialize** function not able to load the html file

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/rhoE1H9A8nfu6II64aEo?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to set up a working example.

Unfortunately Backbone doesn't give you much for free, so there are a number of manual steps to get this working:

1. Add a `<div id="todoapp"></div>` to index.html as you are targeting it with `el: '#todoapp'` but it doesn't exist.
2. Doing `template: _.template(statsTemplate)` will return a compiled version of the template (as a function). You then need to call it like a function, optionally passing in a context so that the template can render dynamic data. e.g. `this.template()`.
3. The `render` method won't get called automatically, so when you are ready to render the view (usually instantly but it could be after an AJAX response) you need to call `this.render()`. In your case straight away in `initialize`.
4. Finally in `render` you can attach the rendered template to the view's element: `this.$el.html(this.template());`

Updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6HyOhuQ7LGL91rS8slJX?p=preview

I recommend you create a BaseView with this common render flow so you don't have to repeat it every time. Also it's a good idea in that BaseView to set up a concept of sub views which clean up properly when the parent's `remove` is called, and re-render when a parent's `render` is called.

Here is an example of using a BaseView: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/xqxcozff/1/

Comment: Thanks for answering could you please tell me how to create baseview ..mean you suggest that could you please change my plunker using base view

Comment: secondly why  is it necessary to add template inside library ? lib/templates/stats.html ..when I added like that js/templates/stats.html.it give error on this line..'text!templates/stats.html'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the second question, but I have given an example of how to use a BaseView in the above answer. Now I've already answered more than the question so the rest is up to you. If you clarify the second question I can answer that too.

Comment: Actually take a look at this file "lib/templates/stats.html" ..Stats.html , which is on lib->templates ->stats.html ..When I insert this stats.html file in js->templates->stats.html file ..and use in this "js/views/app.js" or other words js->views->app.js I am getting error why ? ..it is not able to load this file 'text!templates/stats.html'

Comment: define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'text!templates/stats.html'
],  I will get error when I added httml file in js directory .Inside that directory I create template directory

Comment: I will give you plunker and then you will check

Comment: see this why it is not working http://plnkr.co/edit/wvhxOhes9hevT9yixVkj?p=preview

Comment: @user944513 I see what you mean. I recommend you set `baseUrl` in `main.js` to `js` - this I think should be working but there is something wrong with pinkr - I recommend you try the paths like this but on your local machine: http://plnkr.co/edit/ADn7RzFNfVoOLA5SF98G?p=preview